# how to write sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

### Table : promocode

```
customerid   promocode
------------------------
1            123a-234b
2            123a
3            123a-234b-345c
4            23s-34f
```

I want result as

```
Promocode
--------------
123a,234b
123a
123a,234b,345c
23s,34f
```

plz help me ........

Comment: 1) Learn to speak some basic English.
2) Tell us more about your specific problem. What you wrote above does not allow me to help you in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use REPLACE to change the hyphen character to a comma:

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.promocode, '-', ',')
  FROM PROMOCODE t
```

If you want to write this change to the table:

```
UPDATE PROMOCODE
   SET promocode = REPLACE(t.promocode, '-', ',')
```

If there's no hyphen, nothing is updated.

Reference:

- [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT REPLACE(Promocode, '-', ',') AS Promocode FROM Promocode
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT REPLACE(promocode, '-', ',') 'promocode'
FROM promocode

btw it is not very good practice to be naming your column to be the same name as your table!

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as I can gather from your post, you want to replace "-" with ","

```
SELECT REPLACE(promocode, '-', ',') AS Promocode
  FROM MyTable
```